# PHP mail form trouble shooting

Tags: php

Im quite stuck on this, it's worked in the past when I've made php mail forms, but my brain just isnt working on this one. Any ideas would be very helpful.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {


$email_to = "paulsizer12@gmail.com";
$email_subject = "eKoWeld Feedback";

$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$company_name = $_POST['company_name']; 
$contact_name = $_POST['contact_name']; 
$industry = $_POST['industry'];
$do = $_POST['do']; 
$material = $_POST['material']; 
$TIG_MIG = $_POST['TIG_MIG'];
$Instructions = $_POST['Instructions'];
$easy = $_POST['easy'];
$Before = $_POST['Before']; 
$After = $_POST['After'];
$Savings = $_POST['Savings'];
$recommend = $_POST['recommend'];
$another = $_POST['another'];
$testimonial = $_POST['testimonial']; 




?>
Thank you for leaving feedback.
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: where is your mail function

Comment: You'll need to tell us what the problem is that you are experiencing.

Comment: The problem I'm having is that instead of using the PHP function, when I click submit, it goes to the PHP page, if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

[PHP Mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

You have forget to add mail function

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {


$email_to = "paulsizer12@gmail.com";
$email_subject = "eKoWeld Feedback";

$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$company_name = $_POST['company_name']; 
$contact_name = $_POST['contact_name']; 
$industry = $_POST['industry'];
$do = $_POST['do']; 
$material = $_POST['material']; 
$TIG_MIG = $_POST['TIG_MIG'];
$Instructions = $_POST['Instructions'];
$easy = $_POST['easy'];
$Before = $_POST['Before']; 
$After = $_POST['After'];
$Savings = $_POST['Savings'];
$recommend = $_POST['recommend'];
$another = $_POST['another'];
$testimonial = $_POST['testimonial']; 

 mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); // add this line with your variables 


?>
```

Comment: The problem I'm having is that instead of using the PHP function, when I click submit, it goes to the PHP page, if that makes any sense.